# how to hide a div and then load another

Tags: html

Im trying to hide a div and then replace it with another div which is located into another html file, when the hyperlink is clicked.

How can I do this? I think this is has nothing to do with html right?

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly, JavaScript could get handy here, specially with a couple of jQuery lines. Unless you plan to use hidden iframe elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use javascript to dynamically request the html page and then set the inner html of an element on the page (most likely a div).

Using jquery will simplify your life.

If you have a div where id="result" then you can use the `html()` method to insert the results into your div such as

HTML:

```
<div id="result"/>
```

jquery code:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
$( "#result" ).html( data );
alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ and https://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I am not sure what you are saying.